# Neck and shoulder discomfort

Tags: ergonomics

I have a Raleigh Strada hybrid with flat handlebars.

Have recently been getting some discomfort in the neck and shoulder area which I suspect is down to poor posture on the bike.

Are there any excercises I can do to improve things?

Comment: Are you riding with clip less pedals, where your feet are retained, or on flat pedals with regular shoes?

Comment: The question is somewhat broad and answers could be anything from medical issues to _get more fit by riding more often_. I don't think we can answer it. When you have a better idea what is amiss, we might be able to give you advise. (eg how to strengthen my core)

Comment: Do you have a brim/visor/peak on your helmet?  Consider removing it.

Comment: A photo of you on the bike, from the side, might help us come up with some suggestions to help your overall comfort.  Try editing the photo into your question, which will submit to the reopen queue.  As it stands, medical advise (like recommending exercises) is off topic.   Suggesting improvements to your on-bike posture would be okay.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly your position on the bike is putting too much weight on your hands, or making you lean a little too far forward than you want. Moving the handlebar up and back may help. You may want to check that your saddle is placed correctly. If it's too far forward it reduces your ability to support you body with your legs as much which places more weight on your arms and hands.

You can also try moving your hands into different positions while riding to avoid aches from staying in one position for a long time.

You can try neck and upper body stretching exercises, they might help and it's unlikely they'll do you any harm.